# Iterating through function using multiple starting values

Tags: r

I've written a function that takes a number, x and the number of iterations of the code as arguments and I need to write a code (maybe a whole new function?) using a loop that generates the first 10 values of the sequences starting with each of the values 1, 2, 3, . . . , 20.

```
x=1:20
for (elm in x)
  sequences=dprodseq(elm)
sequences

> sequences
 [1]  20  22  26  38  62  74 102 104 108 122 122
```

which only starts from the last element in the vector.

How do I make the code run the function from each of the elements in the vector?

Comment: Can you show the `dprodseq`.  You may need to initialise the `sequences`. i..e `sequences <- vector('list', length(x)); for(i in seq_along(x)){ sequences[[i]] <- dprodseq(x[i])}`

Comment: Your code already runs for each elements of the vector. However, you store each result in the same place, so it gets overwritten. You could use lapply: `sequences <- lapply(x, dprodseq)`

Comment: For me, it feels more 'natural' to use `sapply` to go through each vector element.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to initialize the object 'sequences'.  Here I am creating 'sequences' as a `list` with length equal to the length of 'x'

```
sequences <- vector('list', length(x))
for(i in seq_along(x)){
    sequences[[i]] <- dprodseq(x[i])
}
```